# PHP JavaScript echo won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my PHP/JS code:

```
echo "<script>
function transformCard() {
document.getElementById('cardImage').src = " . $row['transformedimageurl'] . "
document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = deformCard();
}
function deformCard() {
document.getElementById('cardImage').src = " . $row['imageurl'] . "
document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = transformCard()
}
</script>";
```

My HTML:

```
<button id="transformbtn" onClick="transformCard()"></button>
<img id='cardImage' src="image.jpg" />
```

The button click doesn't change the `src` of my image.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Open developers console. What do you see there? Unexpected token?

Comment: nothing unless i click the button then it says >> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `src` in quotes:

```
echo "<script>
    function transformCard() {
    document.getElementById('cardImage').src = '" . $row['transformedimageurl'] . "';
    document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = deformCard();
}
function deformCard() {
    document.getElementById('cardImage').src = '" . $row['imageurl'] . "';
    document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = transformCard()
}
</script>";
```

You also probably want to remove the `()` on the `onClick` handler:

```
document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = deformCard;
document.getElementById('transformbtn').onClick = transformCard;
```

Comment: It's still saying Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: now in the console it dont gives any errors but a `<img src alt id="cardImage"/>`

Comment: @AMG Probably an infinite loop (the functions call each other). Open the developer tools, go to the "Source" tab and add breakpoints on the first line of each function. Then keep clicking the play button to see how the flow happens.

Comment: oh no now it's working thanks for your help the image didn't react cause the array wasn't created in that piece of the code i placed the echo somewhere else after the array and now it works thanks